# Spring Error Controller is called in every request

Tags: java, spring

There is a strange behavior in my application.
I have an error controller to map some kind of error and have a log of it.

I have this exception

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotAccessibleException extends RuntimeException{

public ResourceNotAccessibleException(String message) {
        super(message); 
}
```

Than, i have this controller

```
@Controller
public class ErrorController {

@GetMapping("/errors")
    @ExceptionHandler({ResourceNotAccessibleException.class})
    public ModelAndView getErrorPage(HttpServletRequest request, RuntimeException ex) {

int httpErrorCode = getErrorCode(request);
String errorMsg = messageSource.getMessage("errorMessage.404", null, locale);
            logger.error("Status Error " + httpErrorCode +  getErrorMessage(request));

ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("errorMessage", errorMsg);
        mav.addObject("errorCode", httpErrorCode);
        mav.setViewName("error");

        return mav;

}
```

I have also a bean pin my configuration to map this error page

```
@Component
public class CustomizationBean implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {



  @Override
  public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {

    container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/errors"));
  }

}
```

Now, the strange behavior is that i see the log of the 404 error in every page of my application, not only when the exception is thrown...

I don't know what else i can provide...

Comment: It sounds like you are linking to some resource that cannot be found on every page (e.g. in the header?). If you try to load a css or js file that is not accessible on every request, Spring might respond with a 404 to every request for that resource.